# explain the code in numpy how its working

Tags: python-3.x, array-broadcasting

this is the code that i run :

```
labels=[0,1,1,0,2,1,1,1,0,0]
labels_ = np.zeros((10, 3))
labels_
```

the above code gives the output :

```
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

now when i run below code "block 2"

```
labels_[np.arange(10), labels] = 1
labels_
```

it gives the output :

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```

can someone explain what happens in the code " block 2" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use square brackets to index NumPy arrays the first number in the bracket refers to the row, and the second number refers to the column - like a game of battleships.

Now, you're indexing an array of zeros called `labels_` using your list called `labels`, and an array created by `np.arange`:

```py
labels_ = array([[0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.]]

labels = [0,1,1,0,2,1,1,1,0,0]

np.arange(10) = array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

As we said before, NumPy indexing goes `[row,column]` and you're using the index `[np.arange(10), labels]`. When you give NumPy multiple values for indexing it uses them in turn, so it looks for the first value in the `np.arange(10)` array and the first item in the `labels` list and uses them as the row index and column index for the zeros array, `labels_`.

We know that the first item in the `np.arange(10)` is 0 and the first item in `labels` is also 0, so it looks in your `labels_` list for [0,0] - the first row and the first column. You've told it to set the indices to 1 with your `= 1` so it does that.

Note that Python counts from 0, so the first row is row 0, the second row is row 1, the third row is row 2 etc. Also note that we count the first row as the top row, and the first column as the left column.

So now we have:

```py
labels_ = array([[1., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.]]
```

Next it looks at the second value in `np.arange(10)` and `labels` and we know that `np.arange(10)[1] = 1` and `labels[1] = 1` so it sets row 1 (the second row) and column 1 (the second column) to 1.

So now we have:

```py
labels_ = array([[1., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 1., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.]]
```

Now we look for the third item in `np.arange(10)` and `labels` and get an index of [2,1] and that's the third row and second column of the `labels_` array, which we set to `:

```py
labels_ = array([[1., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 1., 0.],
                 [0., 1., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0.]]
```

We keep going like this until we run out of numbers in the lists that we're using for indexing.